# Using Java, what is the best way to save an image to a file?

Tags: java, serialization, bufferedimage

I have a school work where I need to save an arbitrary image to the disk along with other data, in a single file.

We thought about serializing it, along with the data; however, images, even `BufferedImage`s, can't be serialized.

What's the <strike>best</strike> simplest way to save an image with other data in a single file, using Java? Honestly, I don't really care about the file size. Though, if it's compressed, I suppose it's a plus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ImageIO.write(img, "BMP", new File("filename.bmp"));
```

where img is your `BufferedImage`.

After that you can open the file with `FileOutputStream` and write some data after or behind.
When reading you just have to cut the appended data and treat the rest as your image.

Comment: And how can I append arbitrary data to this file and still read it with relative ease?

Comment: The OP wrote *"Honestly I don't really care about the file size. Though, if it's compressed, I suppose it's a plus"*. BMP? Really? Make that *.png* :)

Comment: @Webinator Yeah I guessed that part for myself though. (I sent this link to my coworker, I'll accept once he gets it right, which will hopefully be later today.)

Comment: It worked well, although I used the stream variants. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a "readable" solution, as in store in a text file, you could encode the image as a base64 string and store that in your file. There are a [few options in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917604/decode-base64-string-java-5) for Java, for instance the one from [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html).

If you get the `byte[]` as illustrated in the other answers you can get a String by doing

```
String imageString = new Base64().encodeBase64String(imageBytes);
```

And get the byte array back with

```
byte[] imageBytes = new Base64().decodeBase64(imageString);
```