# Base64 decoding using JDK6 only

Tags: base64, java

[This question with regard to JDK 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917604/decode-base64-string-java-5) says, there is no implementation provided with JDK 5, but JDK 6 is supposed to have a `sun.misc.Base64Decoder`.

As far as I can tell though, this class is not provided with the JDK and I was not able to find any other similar classes in it
So, what is the situation like with JDK6?
I am aware of numerous implementations out there like the Commons and the JBoss ones, but we have a restrictive 3rd party lib policy, so I am trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: you should stay await from sun.misc, it's sort of kinky, it rarely changes but when it does it's quite rapid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the situation didn't change between Java 5 and Java 6.

<strike>Unfortunately there is no official Base64 implementation in the Java SE platform.</strike> @bestsss has shown that there **is** in fact a (well-hidden) Base64 implementation in Java SE 6 (see his answer for more detail).

The Sun JDK ships with this class (`sun.misc.Base64Decoder`), but it's not specified and [should not be used](http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq/faq-sun-packages.html) (especially as it's not required to exist in other implementations or even versions).

If you absolutely need to avoid third party libraries ([Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) would be the traditional provider of [a Base64 implementation](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)), then you might want to copy a BSD (or similarly) licensed version into your project. There is a [public domain implementation](http://www.iharder.net/current/java/base64/) and that's about as painless as it gets, when it comes to licenses.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have decided to try the source distribution of the BSD-licensed [MiGBase64 implementation](http://migbase64.sourceforge.net/). It claims to be very fast and to have a small footprint.

Comment: There are an official impl. actually 2 of them.

Comment: It's completely ridiculous that Java does not provide a built-in Base64 encoder/decoder *in a sensible location*.

Answer (score 58):

There are official (non `sun.misc`) implementations in Java, but it's not where anyone suppose to be.

`java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences` is the one that has the necessary methods to do so. You have to override `put` method.

And one more which is much easier to use:

[`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) it has 2 methods of interest:

- [`public static byte[] parseBase64Binary( String lexicalXSDBase64Binary )`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`public static String printBase64Binary( byte[] val )`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printBase64Binary%28byte%5B%5D%29)

---

clarification the base64 nature of AbstractPreferences:
java.util.prefs.Preferences

```
    /**
     * Associates a string representing the specified byte array with the
     * specified key in this preference node.  The associated string is
     * the Base64 encoding of the byte array, as defined in RFC 2045, Section 6.8,
     * with one minor change: the string will consist solely of characters
     * from the Base64 Alphabet; it will not contain any newline
     * characters.  Note that the maximum length of the byte array is limited
     * to three quarters of MAX_VALUE_LENGTH so that the length
     * of the Base64 encoded String does not exceed MAX_VALUE_LENGTH.
     * This method is intended for use in conjunction with
     * {@link #getByteArray}.
     */
    public abstract void putByteArray(String key, byte[] value);
```

Comment: How would you use `AbstractPreferences` in a way that documentation-conforming? It's JavaDoc doesn't mention Base64 *anywhere*.

Comment: `DatatypeConverter` looks great, 'though!

Comment: @Joachim, about the doc, you are wrong :), I will edit the answer

Comment: So the parseBase64Binary is equivalent to Base64.decodeBase64 from commons.encoder? That would be nice (and a bit confusing).

Comment: Ah, I see now! The documentation is in the `Preferences` interfaces. The documentation on `AbstractPreferences` makes no mention of Base 64, that's why I was confused.

Comment: +1 because it's a built-in Base64 en-/decoder which you won't find by your own!

Answer (score 7):

Just like Joachim Sauer said in a previous comment JDK1.6 already comes bundled with it's own Base64 implementation (sun.misc.*), here's an example:

```
String toEncode = "Encoding and Decoding in Base64 Test";
//Encoding in b64
String encoded = new BASE64Encoder().encode(toEncode.getBytes());
System.out.println(encoded);
//Decoding in b64
byte[] decodeResult = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encoded);
System.out.println(new String(decodeResult));
```

Comment: The use of the `sun` package is [discouraged](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

Answer (score 4):

i used  `byte[] decodedValue = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(value);`

this website explains well:
https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0598.html

excerpt from it:

```
   public static String encode(String value) throws Exception {
      return  DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary
          (value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); // use "utf-8" if java 6
   }

   public static String decode(String value) throws Exception {
      byte[] decodedValue = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(value);
      return new String(decodedValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // use "utf-8" if java 6
   }
```

Comment: a suitable solution, test both solutions and have the same result, just to be sure ;-)