# How to create base64Binary data?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, arrays, base64

What is base64Binary and how can I create base64Binary from a given byte array in Java?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: why do you need base64 *binary*, the idea it is that's plains ASCII text. other that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908574/base64-decoding-using-jdk6-only might give you an idea

Comment: @bestsss: It's an XSD data type - the weird name originates there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) with `public static byte[] encodeBase64(byte[] binaryData)`.

Comment: Any way of doing this by using only core Java packages?

Comment: See Maven repo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10. If using Gradle:
add this line into build.gradle: compile "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10"

Answer (score 4):

To create such data you may use the JDK built-in class [sun.misc.BASE64Encoder](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/BASE64Encoder.html). Unfortunately it's not public API since nobody cared to provide a BASE64 en-/decoder in the public API - but people often use this class to circumvent that disadvantage.

[base64Binary](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#base64Binary) is an XML Schema data type, referring to arbitrary binary data that is to be encoded using [BASE64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to retrieve a "safe" string representation of that data - e.g. for embedding binary data in XML, mails etc.

W3C Definition:

> base64Binary represents Base64-encoded arbitrary binary data. The ·value space· of base64Binary is the set of finite-length sequences of binary octets. For base64Binary data the entire binary stream is encoded using the Base64 Alphabet in [RFC 2045].