# How can I get base64 for a file?

Tags: java, email, file-io, base64, mime-types

I have tried using the below code which generates a base64 for the file and returns as string. I was able to get if the file size is small.

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = 
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                        String line = "";           
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();
```

If there is any other way to get the base64 of the file.The command I am passing is base64 filename. please let me know

Comment: BTW, what is `command`?

Comment: you need to tag the language you want

Comment: Even i have you the MIMEBase64 method from [link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0083.html) I was able to generate for smaller file( i tried for .xlsx 16kb, .txt 3kb) I was failing for files .jar 480KB .pdf 3MB. Its taking like eternity for giving the string

Comment: @Amadan its base64 filename.

Comment: @KeithNicholas its java. tq i taged the language

Comment: Whose base64 filename? And why are you executing it? And there is no mention of base64 anywhere in code... I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Amadan In linux we use base64 <filename/path> to get the base64 of the file. so i used the above mentioned java code to execute the command in console and get the output. Apart from this i tried using the algo in method MIMEBase64 [in this link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0083.html). I am trying to append the base64 string in order to add an attachment to the email.  I was able to get the output if the size is small.

Comment: Java 8 consolidated its Base64 classes in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java. Before java 8 see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: I know what `base64` utility is. You wrote "its base64 filename", not "it's" or "it is", which would have allowed me to understand what you are talking about. I thought it `command` was a filename of your data that was encoded in Base64, which made no sense. Anyway, as icza says, you don't need to launch external processes to encode to Base64.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need an external program for this, Java has built-in Base64 encoding/decoding capabilities.

This is all it takes:

```
String base64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(Files.readAllBytes(
    Paths.get("path/to/file")));
```

**Edit:**

If you're using Java 6, `Files` and `Paths` are not availabe (they were added in Java 7.0). Here is a Java 6 compatible solution:

```
File f = new File("path/to/file");
byte[] content = new byte[(int) f.length()];
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream(f);
    for (int off = 0, read;
        (read = in.read(content, off, content.length - off)) > 0;
        off += read);

    String base64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(content);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Some error occured
} finally {
    if (in != null)
        try { in.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Comment: i am using java 1.6. `DatatypeConverter ` is from javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter and for `Files.readAllBytes` ,`Paths.get` do need to use any external jar, as its showing any import from java. (i am developing in ecllipse)

Comment: All the used classes are from the standard Java lib. `Files` and `Paths` were added in Java 7.0.

Comment: Added a Java 6.0 compatible solution.

Comment: superb!! Thanks a lot @icza :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
    String result = Base64.encode(output.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: Please clarify this class. Which package / library is this? Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908574/base64-decoding-using-jdk6-only

Comment: It may be java.util.Base64 in java 8